# import property from xml by WP all import

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

I have xml file which looks like somethin like this:

```
<item id=1>
   <PROPERTIES>
      <PROPERTY><NAME>prop1</NAME><VALUE>value1</PROPERTY>
      <PROPERTY><NAME>prop2</NAME><VALUE>value2</VALUE></PROPERTY>
      <PROPERTY><NAME>prop3</NAME><VALUE>value3</VALUE></PROPERTY>
      <PROPERTY><NAME>prop4</NAME><VALUE>value4</VALUE></PROPERTY>
   </PROPERTIES>
</item>
<item id=2>
   <PROPERTIES>
      <PROPERTY><NAME>prop1</NAME><VALUE>value1</PROPERTY>
      <PROPERTY><NAME>prop999</NAME><VALUE>value2</VALUE></PROPERTY>
      <PROPERTY><NAME>prop1000</NAME><VALUE>value2</VALUE></PROPERTY>
   </PROPERTIES>
</item>
```

I want use plugin called WP all import to export all properties as post meta (name and value) for each post item. Standard way is usingng drag and drop method for every property one by one which create certain index like this:
custom field 1 name:

```
{PROPERTIES[1]/PROPERTY[1]/NAME[1]}
```

custom field 1 value:

```
{PROPERTIES[1]/PROPERTY[1]/VALUE[1]}
```

custom field 2 name:

```
{PROPERTIES[1]/PROPERTY[2]/NAME[1]}
```

custom field 2 value:

```
{PROPERTIES[1]/PROPERTY[2]/VALUE[1]}
```

Does it exists any more automatic solution for for every items? Somethin like 
{PROPERTIES[1]/PROPERTY[*]/NAME[1]}

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Here's the documentation link to Foreach http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/foreach-loops/